# React-Router cannot access to the below routes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am making a simple login app. I have public and private routes. And I also have a variable route that can access to both private and public users. So far I created routes from public and private users. But that variable route for both users is not accessible. How can I solve this issue. I am using router-dom v5

```
     <Route path={"/forgot-password"}>
        <ForgetPwd />
      </Route>

      <Route path={"/verifyEmail"}>
        <EmailVarification />
      </Route>
      <Route path={"/recover-password"}>
        <Recoverpassword />
      </Route>
      <PostProvider>
        <Layout>
          <PrivateRoutes path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoutes>
        </Layout>
      </PostProvider>
      <Route path="/:id?">
        <Publicpage />
      </Route>
```

I Think above question is not very clear. so I will explain my question more

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={"/home"}>
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path={"/"}>
        {/* I need to add some logic to Protect these routes */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/about"}>
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Route>
     {/* This below route cannot access */}
      <Route path={"/:id"}>
        <PublicPage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

I want to create simple react-router but I need public page to display data according to entered code name. And also I need to have some protected routes also. So I created some protected routes and my variable public route placed end of the routes So it will not clash with static routes. My question is after that protected route, react-router is not looking outside that scope. Below routes are not rendered

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Issue

I think I'm reading between the lines here and guessing/assuming that you are rendering these routes within a `Switch` component. If this is the case then the issue is that the ***only*** valid children components of the `Switch` are the `Route` and `Redirect` components. When the `PostProvider` component is reached, route matching ceases and the `PostProvider` component is returned/rendered.

## Solution

Refactor/restructure the components to render the custom `PrivatesRoutes` component at the `Switch` component level so routes can continued to be matched and rendered. Move the `PostProvider` component inside the route.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  ... other more specific routes ...
  <Route path="/forgot-password">
    <ForgetPwd />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/verifyEmail">
    <EmailVarification />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/recover-password">
    <Recoverpassword />
  </Route>
  <PrivateRoutes path="/dashboard">
    <PostProvider> // <-- PostProvider moved into route
      <Layout>     // <-- Layout moved into route
        <Dashboard />
      </Layout>
    </PostProvider>
  </PrivateRoutes>
  <Route path="/:id?">
    <Publicpage />
  </Route>
  ... other routes ...
</Switch>
```

### Update

> ```
> <BrowserRouter>
>   <Switch>
>     <Route path={"/home"}>
>       <Home />
>     </Route>
>     <Route path={"/"}>
>       {/* I need to add some logic to Protect these routes */}
>       <Switch>
>         <Route path={"/about"}>
>           <About />
>         </Route>
>       </Switch>
>     </Route>
>    {/* This below route cannot access */}
>     <Route path={"/:id"}>
>       <PublicPage />
>     </Route>
>   </Switch>
> </BrowserRouter>
> ```

Within the `Switch` component path order and specificity matters. The less specific `path="/"` route is ordered before the `"/:id"` path, so `"/"` will *always* be matched and rendered and any routes listed after will effectively be unreachable.

Within `Switch` components you should order the routes by inverse order of path specificity. `"/home"` is more specific than `"/:id"` is more specific than `"/"`, and this should be the order for these three routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/:id}>
      <PublicPage />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The same holds true when using custom route components.

Example `PrivateRoute` component:

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
  // auth logic
  return isAuth ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <PrivateRoute path="/about">
      <About />
    </PrivateRoute>
    <Route path="/:id}>
      <PublicPage />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think my question is not very clear. I edited it to clear my question more

Comment: @ChathushakaLochana The `"/:id"` path isn't reached/rendered because the simpler/less specific `"/"` route path above it. In the `Switch` component path order and specificity matters.